# Сортировка многомерного массива по дате

Tags: массивы, php, сортировка

Массив неправильно сортируется по дате. Если данные выбраны от 2014-06-01 до 2015-02-15, то сортирует только по месяцам, начиная с января до декабря (2015 идет вперед, потом 2014).

Использовал несколько функций - одно и то же.

```
    function sort1($a, $b){
    if (strtotime($a['DATE']) > strtotime($b['DATE']))
    return 1;
}

function sort3($a, $b){
    if (strtotime($a['DATE']) === strtotime($b['DATE'])) return 0;
    return (strtotime($a['DATE']) > strtotime($b['DATE']))?1:-1;
}

function sort2($a, $b){
    $aa = explode("-", $a['DATE']);
    $ba = explode("-", $b['DATE']);
    if($aa[2]>$ba[2])return 1;
    if($aa[2]<$ba[2])return -1;
    if($aa[1]>$ba[1])return 1;
    if($aa[1]<$ba[1])return -1;
    if($aa[0]>$ba[0])return 1;
    if($aa[0]<$ba[0])return -1;
    return 0;
}
$rows_array[0]['DATE']= "2015-01-01";
$rows_array[0]['NAME']= "Vasya";
$rows_array[1]['DATE']= "2014-01-01";
$rows_array[2]['NAME']= "Kolya";
// итд

usort($rows_array, 'sort3');
```

Comment: @Freqnsy, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да тут достаточно

```
<?php
$a = array(
    array('DATE' => '2014-02-15', 'NAME' => 'Петя'),
    array('DATE' => '2013-01-05', 'NAME' => 'Петя'),
    array('DATE' => '2015-05-01', 'NAME' => 'Вася'),
    array('DATE' => '2014-02-10', 'NAME' => 'Коля'),
    array('DATE' => '2012-01-25', 'NAME' => 'Ира'),
);

function mysort($a, $b) {
    return strtotime($b['DATE']) - strtotime($a['DATE']);
}

usort($a, 'mysort');

echo '<pre>';
print_r($a);
```

И на выходе получим

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [DATE] => 2015-05-01
            [NAME] => Вася
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [DATE] => 2014-02-15
            [NAME] => Петя
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [DATE] => 2014-02-10
            [NAME] => Коля
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [DATE] => 2013-01-05
            [NAME] => Петя
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [DATE] => 2012-01-25
            [NAME] => Ира
        )

)
```